# What does throw() mean , if anything, in Java?

Tags: java, exception

In trying to debug a section of code today, I discovered I had written this:

```
if (testHand[iThread].wasThreadInterrupted()) throw(new InterruptedException());
```

instead of:

```
if (testHand[iThread].wasThreadInterrupted()) throw new InterruptedException();
```

Interestingly this compiled and ran with no problems, but probably wasn't doing what I intended. I've searched for a throw method, but haven't found one - is this some bad way of throwing an exception..why did it compile?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The throws keyword for exceptions in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1989077/the-throws-keyword-for-exceptions-in-java)

Comment: You can put parentheses `(` and `)` around any expression. It doesn't mean anything special. Does it looks less strange if there would have been a space after `throw`? `throw (new InterruptedException());`

Comment: Ah of course. Thanks for the quick explanation.

Comment: comment by Jesper should probably posted as "answer" instead of comment so it can be marked as correct

Comment: If Jesper does, I will mark as such