# Why I m getting Unreported Exception

Tags: java, exception

can you please why error comes in line 13 as unreported exception ,must be caught pr declared to be thrown

```
class Demo {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        try {
            int x = 43 / 0;
        } catch (ArithmeticException ob) {
            throw ob;
        }

        try {
            int x = 43 / 0;
        } catch (Exception ob) {
            throw ob;
        }
        Exception ob = new Exception();
        throw ob;
        // Line 13 unreported exception Exception; must be caught or declared to be thrown
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to add a `throws` clause to your main method declaration: `public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {`

Comment: @markspace he doesn't need a `throws` declaration because he's using `try/catch`.

Comment: @CardinalSystem in his try/catch, he throws the exception.  That's where the problem comes in (it's not really a problem, but he has to declare it).  I didn't test this but I believe that is the answer.

Comment: @CardinalSystem I added throws Exception to main method then it compiles and runtime comes arithmatic exception in line 4

Comment: Oops. I read line 12 xP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a `throws` to the method that throws exceptions as mentioned before as well as all the methods that call that method

Answer (score 1):

At the last line of your code you are throwing an exception but there is nothing handling it. You must do one of two:

1. Surround it with a `try/catch` block
2. Use the `throws` keyword in the method's signature. See this SO question: [The throws keyword for exceptions in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1989077/6400526)

In addition this question: [Why is “throws Exception” necessary when calling a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11589302/6400526)

---

Secondly after adding it the code will compile but when executed will still throw an exception:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero

Reason is that in the `catch` blocks you are re-throwing the exception.

Comment: You mean adding throws in main method

Comment: @chamina - yes. to the main